# Trying to create a WebService to return a 3D Array to populate table with javascript

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript, jquery, web-services

I am trying to create a dynamic table that is being built based on the value of a search text box.  The Table will have probably 6 columns of 20(max) rows.

My problem is I can't figure out how to return the data from the web-service to the JS function in a way that will allow me to extract the data that I need.

Here is the web-service method I have currently:

```
[WebMethod]
public v_EMU_AIR_AIR[] GetCompletionList(string prefixText)
{
    NeoDataContext dataContext = new NeoDataContext();

    var results = from a in dataContext.GetTable<v_EMU_AIR_AIR>()
                  where a.Report_Date_ID.StartsWith(prefixText) ||
                  a.Item_Description.Contains(prefixText) ||
                  a.Drw_Nbr.StartsWith(prefixText)
                  select a;

    return results.ToArray<v_EMU_AIR_AIR>();

}
```

This will return an Array my objects, but in my javascript:

```
populateTable:function(returnList) {

    var length = returnList.childNodes[0].childNodes.length

    for(var i=0; i<length; i++) {

        var textValue = returnList.childNodes[0].childNodes[i].textContent

         $("<tr><td>" + textValue + "</td></tr>").insertAfter(this.tblResults[0].childNodes[1]);                   
    }
}
```

All I can produce is a dump of the entire Object and can't pull out the specific fields that I need.

Comment: Have you considered returning your information in XML/JSON format, instead of a serialized object array ("v_EMU_AIR_AIR")?

Comment: Yeah I guess I'm just not really sure how to go about that.  Kind of new to this.

Comment: Check these out: http://www.json.org/js.html ; http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON

Comment: @XpiritO: With respect, if you don't understand web services, why are you commenting? The web service framework will obviously serialize the return value, probably to XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would serialize your object using Javascript Object Notation (JSON).

Unfortunately, this feature isn't built in to the .NET framework, so you'll need to write the code yourself.

Fortunately, most of it is already done for you.  Check out [this link](http://keithhill.spaces.live.com/Blog/cns!5A8D2641E0963A97!515.entry) or [this link](http://www.dotnetkicks.com/ajax/Writing_a_full_JSON_Serializer_in_100_lines_of_C_code) for more information.

In your javascript, you can retreive the JSON object with jquery ([documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)) and access the values of your properties like you would in C#

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON("http://url.to.webservice.com/", function(jsonObj) {
        alert(jsonObj.property);
    });
});
```